# How do I sync my Facebook Friends contacts with Flickr contacts?

Tags: facebook, contacts, flickr

As of June , Flickr and Facebook are now [connected](http://www.flickr.com/help/extending/) such that any time I upload a Flickr Photo it gets posted to my feed.

Is there a way to use this same connection to sync contacts (or at least those who have the Flickr/Facebook feature) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless a) flickr has an "import facebook friends", or b) facebook has a "find friends in flickr" feature ... then no.

Unfortunately, I haven't seen this so I don't think this is available at the time of this answer.

Comment: Supposedly its possible one way http://fbfriendfinder.com/fbfriendfinder_import_flickr.php but I am still reading reviews for it.